# regex fail to pick the group correctly

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some issue with generating the regex to capture part of a string

lets say I have two strings

```
str1 = "<abc>ghk45<\abc>"
str2 = "<abc>ghk45"
```

I need to capture "abc" in first angle brackets and "ghk45" using a regex, that will work for either of above strings

I tried following regex but I couldnot grab second part correctly

```
<(abc)>(.+)<?
```

if I use this on `str1`
I can get abc in group 1
but for group 2 I get "ghk45<\abc>"

if I use above regex on str2, it returns both groups correctly.

I'm scratching my brain for hours and tried lot of combinations and had no luck.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Use `<(abc)>([^<]+)`

Comment: What about `str3 = "<abc>ghji<def>klm<\def>nop` and `str4 = "<abc>ghji<def>klm<\def>nop<\abc>`